# How to Debug a Datapipeline within Time Constraints

Tags: python, database, etl, pipeline

This was a question that was asked of me during a job interview. I'm curious how those in the stack overflow community would answer this question:

> You are in charge of developing a data pipeline. You are to hand over control of this data pipeline in 24 hours to a different team when, suddenly, an exception is raised somewhere within the pipeline. The pipeline is complex enough that running the pipeline from start to finish takes longer than 24 hours to complete. How do you debug this pipeline before you hand it off to a different team?

My answer to the question was to import the relevant/buggy module to my local environment, take some toy data, and try to first replicate the bug and then identify what changes need to be made within that module--but I suspect there may be a better way to solve this problem.